What is the difference between these two connection to mongodb in node.js ; connect-mongo, or without it
I came across two different ways of connecting to MongoDB in Node.js. What is the difference?
And when should I use each one?
1-
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/notes_local')
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`Connected successfully to DataBase notes_local on port ${port}................. `);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log('error: ', err));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
}))

2-
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard Deer',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({            
        mongoUrl: process.env.MONGODB_URI
    }),
    cookie: { maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000) }
}))


For the first one (using mongoose)
you are using mongoose to directly connect to your mongoDB.
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/notes_local')

After connecting, you're setting up sessions with express-session but not using MongoDB to store session information.
the second option: Using connect-mongo with sessions.
connect-mongo is used with sessions in Express apps to store session information in your MongoDB.
When to use each?

Use mongoose directly when you're dealing with the database for regular CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations. It's straightforward and lets you manage your data efficiently.

Use connect-mongo with sessions when you want to save session information in MongoDB. It's useful for keeping track of user sessions, especially if your app has login features



Thank you, I created a web site which has login features, If I use the first method (mongoose directly) , will there be problems saving data for users? I need more clarification to understand why I have to use the second method.

Mongoose is perfectly fine for saving data. The second is for saving session information
